# @Transactional and @Audited

Tags: database

in application when we perform curd operation  we are auditing transaction using @Audited(Hibernate Envers) in entity class declared , for multiple records also no issue we can audit successful. but when i applied @Transactional on method in service layer getting unique constraint violated error in workflow table, please suggest to avoid this error and save in workflow table as well. please suggest any solution for this.

how to use @audited and @Transactional together and save record in workflow table as well.